# correct usage of ParallelTable

Tags: function-construction, parallelization, list-manipulation

I am trying to parallelize my script. Here is a MWE of how I have done it:

```
LaunchKernels[2];

container = {};
SetSharedVariable[container];

fun[x_] := 2*x;
container = ParallelTable[{i, fun[i]}, {i, 1, 3}];
```

I am unsure if this is done correctly. There are mainly two things I am concerned about when using `ParallelTable`:

1. Is it necessary to parallelize the expression to be looped, i.e. `fun`?
2. Is it necessary to make the `container` with the `ParallelTable`-results a shared variable?

Comment: 1. I believe in the most recent versions not necessary 2. No, don't do it as you did. This is only necessary for variables that you want to have shared *during* the parallel calculations.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Adding to 1. From the documentation: "The default value is `DistributedContexts:>$DistributedContexts` with `$DistributedContexts:=$Context`, which distributes definitions of all symbols in the current context, but does not distribute definitions of symbols from packages." So you are right!